# Extened jakarta.persistence.Entity for CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am autogenerating my Entities and i want to extend them for customization so i can regenerate them if someone modifies the schema but i cant find anyone doing this. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CaribbeanCountry", schema = "table")
public class CaribbeanCountryEntity {
 // AUTO GENERATED
}

public class CaribbeanCountry extends CaribbeanCountryEntity {
}


public interface CaribbeanCountryRepository extends CrudRepository<CaribbeanCountry, Long> {
}
```

I found a good post using the recommendations from @Sametcey

Spring Boot – Map Entity to DTO using ModelMapper
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-map-entity-to-dto-using-modelmapper/

Comment: The error is not related to your question. This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Funny that the person who answered it had no problem .. thanks for nothing @RomanC

Comment: But the answer is wrong -DTOs separate from the entities is advisable, especially if you need to version public REST API, but you'll still have issues if you ever regenerate your entities. Regenerating entities is itself a problem, and not something you should be doing once an app is stable - these are objects used by your application, so just adding removing properties is bound to cause issues for the app; your DTO and how its mapped will similarly need to change. If making schema changes, you need to update the entities similarly to ensure the application is compatible with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the Wrong way! you must use DTO for that!

for Example you have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CaribbeanCountry", schema = "table")
public class CaribbeanCountryEntity {
  private String county;
  private String city;
  ...
}
```

Then you have a DTO like:

```
 public class CaribbeanCountryEntityDTO {
      private String county;
      private String city;
      ...
      private String customthink;

    }
```

After that you must Copy (for that you can use a Mapper like modelMapper) Object to the DTO object und you must then return the DTO custom object.